# How can I get a full Backup from a Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm new to Docker and created myself a Container using a Compose File.
Now I came to a point where I wanted to use my development result in production.
Is there any way to backup the whole content so that I can use it in a production environment ?

The compose file that I used to spin up my Container:

```
    version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myRootPassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_oxygen
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress_oxygen
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: myDBPassword

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose is not for production. For production try docker swarm.
Also you should add volume for wordpress, see example

https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress

How backup volumes please see https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Comment: I guess I explained it a little bit to difficult.
I already have my Container running, This container was created with docker-compose, now I just need to know how to create a volume or maybe even a complete image of my docker container.

Comment: You have two container one for db service and second for wordpress. For backup db volume you can use instruction from answer. For backup wordpress  you can simple copy files which you need from container to host: docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/in/container/file /host/local/path/file.

Comment: Containers themselves should be stateless and they do not need to backup.

Comment: Also use latest in container version is bad practice, because you can have problem when you try restore your backup. You should point specific version. For example 5.6.0-php7.3-apache.

Comment: And remember Volume is an abstraction of simple folder. You should learn docker basics first. The best docs here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/